# Proving that a Sequence is Unbounded - $a_{n+1}=e^{a_n}-1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Here's my question:

> Let $a_1>0$ and $a_n$ be a sequence such that: $$a_{n+1}=e^{a_n}-1$$

Prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$.

**I have proven that the sequence is monotonic increasing, with the following Lemma.**

**Lemma**
$$e^x>x+1$$

(Proven).

With the Lemma, I can write that sequence like that:

$$a_{n+1}-a_n=e^{a_n}-1-a_n\Rightarrow e^{a_n}>a_n+1$$

Therefore the sequence is monotonic increasing.

How do I prove it's unbounded?
 If I do prove it's unbounded, then its limit would be $\infty$.

Thanks,

Alan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Lemma $1$, $e^x>1+x$ for $x>0$, we have

$$a_{n+1}-a_n=e^{a_n}-1-a_n>0\implies a_n\,\,\text{is increasing monotonically}$$

Assume that $a_n$ is bounded.  Then, we would have $a_n\to L$ for some real number $L$.  Then,

$$\lim_{n\to \infty }a_{n+1}=L=e^L-1$$

But, $e^L-1>L$ and we have the desired contradiction!

Therefore, $a_n$ is unbounded.

Comment: As my answer shows, you just need to use $e^x > 1+x+x^2/2$.

Comment: @martycohen That's fine.  There is more than one way to skin a sequence as a wise man once told me.

Comment: Nice answer @Dr.MV.

Comment: @kobe Wow!  Thank you.  Coming from you, that means a lot!  Much appreciative.

Answer (score 1):

$a_{n+1}
=e^{a_n}-1
\ge (1+a_n+a_n^2/2)-1
=a_n(1+a_n/2)
$.
Therefore
$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}
> 1+a_n/2
$.
Therefore,
for any $k$,
$\frac{a_{n+k+1}}{a_{n+k}}
> 1+a_{n+k}/2
> 1+a_{n}/2
$
since
$a_n$ is increasing.

Multiplying these,
$\frac{a_{n+k}}{a_{n}}
> (1+a_{n}/2)^k
> 1+ka_n/2
$
which shows the
divergence.